# SQL Server insert into same values for some columns

Tags: sql-server

There is a table called : `Rules`

This table has PK: `RuleID`, `HouseID`, `StartDate` `EndDate` and `Value`.

I must insert the following entries for 350 HouseIds.

The entries must be looking like this:

```
RuleID            HouseId   StartDate     EndDate    Value
__________________________________________________________
1st id generated  1stId   2015-12-24   2015-12-25   0
2nd id generated  2ndId   2015-12-24   2015-12-25   0
```

and so on.. As you can see, only the `HouseId` is changing (I want to take it from the list, for all the 350 houseids I want to insert some entries having a specific value for startdate, enddate, value).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Rules (HouseId, StartDate, EndDate, Value)
SELECT HouseId, '2015-12-24'. '2015-12-25', 0
FROM Houses
```

Comment: You beat me to it! Just to add to this, if you want to do multiple inserts at once you can use UNION ALL. This will save you from writing the 'INSERT INTO RULES(HouseID, StartDate, EnDate, Vaue)' for each record you are inserting. Example [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/08/sql-server-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-union-all/)